# Linux Shell Script - Back up / Restore

Tags: linux, shell

Hi Community of Stackoverflow,

I am facing a problem here with my shell script that I am designing...

```
#!/bin/sh
while :
do
clear
echo "-----------------------------
-----------"
echo "***************Main Menu****************"
echo "----------------------------------------"
echo "1. Backup Word Document"
echo "2. Backup Spreadsheet"
echo "3. Backup Picture"
echo "4. Restore Word Documents"
echo "5. Restore Spreadsheet"
echo "6. Restore Picture"
echo "7. EXIT"

echo "----------------------------------------"
pause
echo -n "Enter your menu choice [1-7]:"
read yourch
case $yourch in
1) echo ; tar -cvf /Files/*.doc /WP/ ; read ;;

1) echo "Today is";  date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M 2>&1 ; echo "Press a key..." ; read ;;

2) echo ; tar -cvf /Files/*.xls /EXCEL/ ; read ;;

2) echo "Today is";  date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M 2>&1 ; echo "Press a key..." ; read ;;

3) echo ; tar -cvf /Files/*.jpg /PICS/ ; read ;;

3) echo "Today is";  date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M 2>&1 ; echo "Press a key..." ; read ;;

4) echo ; tar xvzf /WP/*.doc ; read ;;
5) echo ; tar xvzf /EXCEL/*.xls ; read ;;
6) echo ; tar xvzf /PICS/*.jpg ; read ;;
7) exit 0 ;;

*) echo "Please press a number between 1 to 7";
```

A error displays 'cript: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token 'in
                 'cript: line 21: 'case $yourch

Does anyone know how to by pass this error? Basically what im trying to do is be able to back up a set of files with the file name ".doc" and place them in a backup folder. I can then restore the files from this folder to another folder.

Kind Regards,

Ben

Comment: @KiranChandrashekhar I have added esac to the bottom of the script but it won't go past line 21.

Comment: This code is wrong, You cannot use multiple case statements

Comment: @KiranChandrashekhar Yes I have just found out that there are syntax errors within the statements, but I don't know exactly where. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I just gave the working code for you. Are you still facing problem ?

Comment: I have typed it what you put and its now going back to line 21 "Syntax error near unexpected token 'in " –

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing  `esac` and `done`  statement.

Ok. Use this one :

```
#!/bin/sh
while :
do
  clear
  echo "-----------------------------
  -----------"
  echo "***************Main Menu****************"
  echo "----------------------------------------"
  echo "1. Backup Word Document"
  echo "2. Backup Spreadsheet"
  echo "3. Backup Picture"
  echo "4. Restore Word Documents"
  echo "5. Restore Spreadsheet"
  echo "6. Restore Picture"
  echo "7. EXIT"

  echo "----------------------------------------"

  echo -n "Enter your menu choice [1-7]:"
  read yourch
  case $yourch in
      1) echo ; 
     tar -cvf /Files/*.doc /WP/ ; read ;
     echo "Today is";  date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M 2>&1 ; echo "Press a key..." ; read ;;

      2)  echo ; tar -cvf /Files/*.xls /EXCEL/ ; read ;
      echo "Today is";  date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M 2>&1 ; echo "Press a key..." ; read ;;

      3) echo ; tar -cvf /Files/*.jpg /PICS/ ; read ;
     echo "Today is";  date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M 2>&1 ; echo "Press a key..." ; read ;;

      4) echo ; tar xvzf /WP/*.doc ; read ;;
      5) echo ; tar xvzf /EXCEL/*.xls ; read ;;
      6) echo ; tar xvzf /PICS/*.jpg ; read ;;
      7) exit 0 ;;

  *) echo "Please press a number between 1 to 7";;

  esac
done
```

Comment: Where should these be placed, I tried adding esac, does it need to be combined with done?

Comment: `esac` is to end the case statement and `done` is to end the do-while loop. As I see it, you need to put it at the end of the code (`esac ` first) :)

Comment: I have put esac under *) echo "Please press a number between 1 to 7"); I have also added "Done" right under it. but it still shows the same error

Comment: Well, Here is my understanding: YOu cannot have two case statements 1) and 1). Combine all the statements under 1) and 2) and remove pause statement and use sleep command instead. I hope it works

Comment: Hi Kiran, I have added in "Sleep 1" instead of the pause statement. I have also removed the "Echo Todays Date" statements for the time being. It is still getting stuck at line 21 though :(

Comment: What is Line no 21  in your code ?  I dont see any error in your code

Comment: Hm now moved onto line 22, by retyping it in. Apparently copy and paste isn't a great way to transfer stuff when scripting.

Comment: I have typed it what you put and its now going back to line 21 "Syntax error near unexpected token 'in "

Comment: I am not sure, why there is a error. I would change the first line to #!/bin/bash instead and run